# Why some people are boring and some are interesting?

Tags: life, meaning-of-life

Why we basically group people into interesting and boring (or any other), can anyone share some of their experiences related to this?

Comment: Why some dogs are white and some are black ?

Comment: charisma is a higlly valued quality.

Comment: Why some questions are boring and some are interesting?

Answer (score 1):

## In my own experience

I have found that  I tend to make the judgements "interesting" and "boring" about people if I am actively looking to make friends.

## Efficiency Argument

Perhaps we choose our friends with a certain pragmatism in mind, a la Darwinian theory. We want our friends to hold to our own standards, so we create a selection process through which we choose friends who cause us to think those judgements that we deem "good."

## Philosophical Rigor

There are many reasons to label a person just as there are many ways to make friends. In the end, we want to spend time with people who effect positive vibes. Constructing a dichotomy between interesting and boring is just one way to understand people.

Comment: Where does this notion of categorization of people emerge into one's mind in the first place? Is it society driven? Is it within us, like u have mentioned? And is it same for everyone?